# How does Instagram's zooming work?

Tags: ios, swift, imageview

I'm not talking about how pinch to zooming works here.

Any one noticed Instagram's zooming? It works as a default pinch to work but when you start zooming in it imageView  expands to the whole screen of device, how do they it so smoothly? Anyone know can point out that?

Answer (score 5):

I created a simple Github project that does exactly what you're after. Check it out here:
https://github.com/twomedia/TMImageZoom

I achieved this by creating a class that handled the gesture state changes. I then create a UIImageView on the window and position/size it to the original image view creating the effect of the user zooming the imageView. Here's a small snippet from the above link:

```
-(void) gestureStateChanged:(id)gesture withZoomImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView {

// Insure user is passing correct UIPinchGestureRecognizer class.
if (![gesture isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    NSLog(@"(TMImageZoom): Must be using a UIPinchGestureRecognizer, currently you're using a: %@",[gesture class]);
    return;
}

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *theGesture = gesture;

// Prevent animation issues if currently animating reset.
if (isAnimatingReset) {
    return;
}

// Reset zoom if state = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
if (theGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || theGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || theGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {
    [self resetImageZoom];
}

// Ignore other views trying to start zoom if already zooming with another view
if (isHandlingGesture && hostImageView != imageView) {
    NSLog(@"(TMImageZoom): 'gestureStateChanged:' ignored since this imageView isnt being tracked");
    return;
}

// Start handling gestures if state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan and not already handling gestures.
if (!isHandlingGesture && theGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    isHandlingGesture = YES;

    // Set Host ImageView
    hostImageView = imageView;
    imageView.hidden = YES;

    // Convert local point to window coordinates
    CGPoint point = [imageView convertPoint:imageView.frame.origin toView:nil];
    startingRect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);

    // Post Notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TMImageZoom_Started_Zoom_Notification object:nil];

    // Get current window and set starting vars
    UIWindow *currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    firstCenterPoint = [theGesture locationInView:currentWindow];

    // Init zoom ImageView
    currentImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageView.image];
    currentImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [currentImageView setFrame:startingRect];
    [currentWindow addSubview:currentImageView];
}

// Reset if user removes a finger (Since center calculation would cause image to jump to finger as center. Maybe this could be improved later)
if (theGesture.numberOfTouches < 2) {
    [self resetImageZoom];
    return;
}

// Update scale & center
if (theGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    NSLog(@"gesture.scale = %f", theGesture.scale);

    // Calculate new image scale.
    CGFloat currentScale = currentImageView.frame.size.width / startingRect.size.width;
    CGFloat newScale = currentScale * theGesture.scale;
    [currentImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(currentImageView.frame.origin.x, currentImageView.frame.origin.y, startingRect.size.width*newScale, startingRect.size.height*newScale)];

    // Calculate new center
    UIWindow *currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    int centerXDif = firstCenterPoint.x-[theGesture locationInView:currentWindow].x;
    int centerYDif = firstCenterPoint.y-[theGesture locationInView:currentWindow].y;
    currentImageView.center = CGPointMake((startingRect.origin.x+(startingRect.size.width/2))-centerXDif, (startingRect.origin.y+(startingRect.size.height/2))-centerYDif);

    // Reset gesture scale
    theGesture.scale = 1;
}
}
```

Comment: Hello, any sample codes on how to use this in UICollectionView? Because it is the most probable use case scenario. Thank you

Comment: @thomas-maw thanks for the code, helped alot

Answer (score 1):

One way to replicate this behavior might be to add a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to your `UIImageView`.  Then use the `scale` property of the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and scale the frame of the `UIImageView` accordingly. [example](https://i.imgur.com/iOdvMW8.gifv)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use third-party library for this. They are always easy to integrate & use.

Try to check on these:

- https://github.com/NYTimes/NYTPhotoViewer
- This one is not inspiring confidence https://github.com/StuartMorris0/SPMZoomableUIImageView

[Official apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html)

[Rey Wenderlish guides are pretty nice too](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122139/uiscrollview-tutorial)

In any case, just **Google it!** and good luck!